# How can I enable panning in react-zoom-pan-pinch? When I pan with two fingers in same direction, it only zooms in but I want it to move with fingers

Tags: reactjs, npm, web, frontend

This is the component. How can I fix it?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import { Slider, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CropFree, PanTool, Add, Remove } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MySVGComponent from "../../assets/svg/RadialTree";

const Svgzoom = () => {
  const [pan, setPan] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <TransformWrapper
        initialScale={2}
        initialPositionX={0}
        initialPositionY={0}
        options={{
          limitToBounds: false, // Allow panning outside the SVG boundaries
        }}
      >
        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, centerView, state }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="toolsZoom">
              <IconButton onClick={() => zoomIn()} style={{ padding: "1px" }}>
                <Add style={{ color: "grey" }} />
              </IconButton>
              <span
                style={{
                  height: "min(400px, 100%)",
                  marginTop: "8px",
                  marginBottom: "8px",
                }}
              >
                <Slider
                  orientation="vertical"
                  aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-small-steps"
                  step={0.1}
                  min={1}
                  max={6}
                  onChange={(e, newValue) => {
                    if (state.scale > newValue) {
                      zoomOut();
                    } else if (state.scale < newValue) {
                      zoomIn();
                    }
                  }}
                  value={state.scale}
                  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                />
              </span>
              <IconButton onClick={() => zoomOut()} style={{ padding: "1px" }}>
                <Remove style={{ color: "grey" }} />
              </IconButton>
              <CropFree
                style={{ color: "#3F51B5", cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => centerView(2)}
              />
              <PanTool
                style={{
                  color: pan ? "#3F51B5" : "#999",
                  fontSize: "22px",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  marginTop: 10,
                }}
                onClick={() => setPan(!pan)}
              />
            </div>
            <div
              id="transformComponentContainer"
              style={{
                margin: "10px",
                border: "3px solid gray",
                borderRadius: "20px",
                cursor: pan ? "-webkit-grab" : "initial",
              }}
            >
              <TransformComponent>
                <MySVGComponent/>
              </TransformComponent>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Svgzoom;
```

I tried to check the onPanning, onPanningStart and onPanningStop but not working. The version I have in package is "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^2.1.3",

```
<TransformWrapper
    initialScale={2}
    initialPositionX={0}
    initialPositionY={0}
    options={{
    limitToBounds: false, // Allow panning outside the SVG boundaries
    onPanning: (a, e)=>{
    console.log('hello onPanning', e)
    },
    onPanningStart: (a, e)=>{
    console.log('hello onPanningStart', e)
    },
    onPanningStop: (a, e)=>{
    console.log('hello onPanningStop', e)
    }
    }}
>
```